# Supabase middleware for business logic

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

New to the supabase universe. Simple questions

Is there a way to setup middleware in supabase?. Can Supabase fulfill this?

- Add business logic middleware when creating an entity
- Add special validations (ie: validate a product has stock before purchase)
- Restrict information depending on user roles (ie: admins can read additional entity attributes, but not common users).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is now solvable using Supabase's Edge Functions: https://supabase.com/docs/guides/functions

There is an example here to solve "Restrict information depending on user roles" using Postgres' Row Level Security:

https://github.com/supabase/supabase/blob/master/examples/edge-functions/supabase/functions/select-from-table-with-auth-rls/index.ts

```js
/ Follow this setup guide to integrate the Deno language server with your editor:
// https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/setup_your_environment
// This enables autocomplete, go to definition, etc.

import { serve } from 'https://deno.land/std@0.131.0/http/server.ts'
import { supabaseClient } from '../_shared/supabaseClient.ts'
import { corsHeaders } from '../_shared/cors.ts'

console.log(`Function "select-from-table-with-auth-rls" up and running!`)

serve(async (req: Request) => {
  // This is needed if you're planning to invoke your function from a browser.
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return new Response('ok', { headers: corsHeaders })
  }

  try {
    // Set the Auth context of the user that called the function.
    // This way your row-level-security (RLS) policies are applied.
    supabaseClient.auth.setAuth(req.headers.get('Authorization')!.replace('Bearer ', ''))

    const { data, error } = await supabaseClient.from('users').select('*')
    console.log({ data, error })

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ data, error }), {
      headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      status: 200,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }), {
      headers: { ...corsHeaders, 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      status: 400,
    })
  }
})
```